# Jquery selector this with data attr

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, this

I have the following code:

```
$(".wishlist-icon").click(function() {
  $(".wishlist-icon[data-wish-name='product']").hide();
});
```

I wan't to change the selector inside the function to "this", but it's not working for me. How should I type it out?

So if "this" has data-wish-name='product', then hide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do:

```
$(".wishlist-icon").click(function() {
    if($(this).data('wish-name') == "product") {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do in two ways:

**1)**

```
$(".wishlist-icon").click(function() {
    if($(this).attr('data-wish-name') == "product") {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

**2)**

```
 $(".wishlist-icon").click(function() {
        if($(this).data('wish-name') == "product") {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
```

Comment: you are welcome,, and i always feel happy when somebody got help from my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".wishlist-icon").click(function() {
  $(this).find("[data-wish-name='product']").hide();
});
```